# Zipkin isnt tracing whole request flow, but as separate request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have common set up for microservices with discovery server( eureka ), api-gateway and services.

Now i am using zipking for distributed tracing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have order services, that internally calls another service to retreive info, In order service i am using this piece of code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

And call:

```
   private final WebClient.Builder webClient;

   ....

   InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponseArray = webClient.build().get()
            .uri("http://inventory-service/api/inventory",
                    uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
            .block();
```

The functionality of this flow works as it should, however when i look into zipking i get:
[image]

e.g zipking isnt tracing the call from `order-service` to `inventory-service`. But when i look in zipkin i see call to the `inventory-service` with different `traceId`

[image]

Why isnt the call to `inventory-service` shown in the flow  but as separate call? I have created WebBuilder as bean which means the spring should inject some `HttpInterceptor` that should add the traceId/spanId.

Comment: Hi @Johnyb Did you get a chance to resolve this issue? Thank you